# Simply C loop is driving me nuts

Tags: c

So I have only ever programmed in c++, but I have to do a small homework that requires the use of c. The problem I encountered is where I need a loop to read in numbers separated by spaces from the user (like: 1 5 6 7 3 42 5) and then take those numbers and fill an array.

the code I wrote is this:

```
int i, input, array[10];

for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
scanf("%d", &input);
array[i] = input;
}
```

EDIT: added array definition.
any suggestions or hints would be very highly appreciated.

Comment: So what goes wrong when you run this?

Comment: Where's your array definition?

Comment: Please show us the declaration for `array`.

Comment: What's the problem with your code? It appears to work here with a few modifications ... mostly `#include` and proper `main`

Comment: Works just fine here gcc 4.4.3 what's the error that you're getting?

Comment: I have a print statement that prints back the values later in the program, but they either come up as zero, or some other garbage.

Answer (score 2):

Irrespective of whatever is wrong here, you should quickly learn to NEVER write code that does not check the return value from any API call that you make.  `scanf` returns a value, and you have to be interested in what it says.  If the call fails, your logic is different, yes?

Perhaps in this case it would tell you what's going wrong.  The docs are [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9y6s16x1.aspx).

> Returns the number of fields
>   successfully converted and assigned;
>   the return value does not include
>   fields that were read but not
>   assigned. A return value of 0
>   indicates that no fields were
>   assigned.

Answer (score 0):

This code working good.

If your numbers is less than 10, then you must know how many numbers is before you start reading this numbers, or last number must be something like 0 to terminate output then you can do `while(true)` loop, but for dynamically solution you must read all line into string and then using `sscanf` to reading numbers from this string.

Comment: it doesn't.. if you hit enter after fewer than 10 integers, the program will still wait for you to type more...

Comment: scanf() will skip white pages preceeding integer values, so the returns you press are jsut skipped. The loop as coded will attempt to fetch 10 integers, regardless of how many returns you press.

Comment: scanf() is an unsafe routine to use a lot of the time, far preferred for you to investigate fgets() and sscanf().

Answer (score 0):

You need the right `#include` and a proper main. The following works for me

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {

    /* YOUR CODE begin */
    int i, input, array[10];
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &input);
        array[i] = input;
    }
    /* end of YOUR CODE */

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

i'm not a c programmer but i can suggest an algorithm which is to use scanf("%s",&str) to read all the input into a char[] array then loop over it and test using an if statment if the current char is a space, if it is then add the preceeding number to the array

Comment: You then may also suggest him how to allocate a big enough buffer to hold the str.